# How to troubleshoot C code that is not working?

Tags: c

Here is my challenge:

> Add sum of two integer values and sum of two double values and concatenate two char array values.
>
> 1. Declare  variables: one of type int, one of type double, and one of type String.
> 2. Read  lines of input from stdin (according to the sequence given in the Input Format section below) and initialize your  variables.
> 3. Use the  operator to perform the following operations: 
>      a.Print the sum of  plus your int variable on a new line.
>      b.Print the sum of  plus your double variable to a scale of one decimal place on a new line.
>      c.Concatenate  with the string you read as input and print the result on a new line.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    char s[] = "HackerRank ";
 // Declare second integer, double, and String variables.
    int j = 5;
    double f = 5.0;
    char a[] = "BestPlace" ;
// Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.
    scanf("%d%d%1f%1f%c%c", &i, &j, &d, &f, &s, &a);
// Print the sum of the integer variables on a new line.
    int sum;
    sum = i+j
    printf("sum of %d", sum);
// Print the sum of the double variables on a new line.
    double s2 = d + f;
    printf("sum of %1f", s2);
// Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line
    strcat(s, a);
    printf(s + strlen(s) , a + strlen(a) , "%c", "%c");
// The 's' variable above should be printed first.
    printf("%c" , s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code ? Doesn't it compile. Doesn't it run ? Does it crash ? Did it format your hard drive ?

Comment: It would help if you gave your post a better more descriptive title, and if you explained what troubles you're facing. Help us help you.

Comment: Hint: `strcat(s, a);` is problematic here. Read more about strings.

Comment: Also `printf("%c", s);` where `s` is a character array makes no sense and will give you undefined behavior. Please compile with all warnings you can get, and read them. Then fix your code.

Comment: First, compile with all warnings then fix them.  Next, run the program through a debugger, again fixing all problems.  Finally, if you can't figure it out, post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

`sum = i+j` This statement does not have a semicolon and post the problem you are facing not the code as it is . First see that the code is error free

Answer (score -3):

In wrong way you are handling the array. first read the array concept and try again.

printf("%c" , s); will print only initial value with is "HackerRank ".

strcat(s, a); will generate the new string object.